# Span formula over multiple pages.

Tags: equations, amsmath

I've looked through the search but I couldn't find what I specifically want.

I have the following

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Very long equation
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Now, I have half a page left where I want to place that equation, but it is a little bit longer. The result is that LaTeX places the formula on the next page. Is there a way so that LaTeX automatically splits the equation over the two pages?

Comment: Jonas, I've marked up your code by leaving a blank line before the block starts. I've also removed the `$` around 'LaTeX': the style we go for here is simply mixed case for TeX, LaTeX, _etc_.

Comment: You should consider breaking your formula in two or more pieces and put a line or paragraph with some explanation in-between.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not if you use `split`. Section 3.9 of the [amsmath](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) package documentation says that

> Certain equation environments wrap their contents in an unbreakable box, with the consequence that neither `\displaybreak` nor `\allowdisplaybreaks` will have any effect on them. These include `split`, `aligned`, `gathered`, and `alignedat`.

The same section explains how to get the effect you need, using a different environment such as `align` or `multline`.

Comment: Thanks. I see I also need to do: ``\allowdisplaybreaks[1]'' or something like that in the preamble.

Comment: @Jonas T - Indeed. I have edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Just a clarification: adding `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the Preamble allows a break to occur anywhere. If you don't want a specific line to be broken, then instead of using \\ to break a line, use \\\*.