# Scoping \raggedbottom to a single page

Tags: scoping

**How does one define a single page to be `\raggedbottom`? Or, for completion's sake, `\flushbottom`?**

### Background

In [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21721/18982) to a related answer, Ben Lerner provided the following snippet of code to declare a single page to be `\raggedbottom`:

```
\def\oneraggedpage{\raggedbottom\afterpage{\flushbottom}}
```

When I tried this, it did not work as expected: instead of making a single page `\raggedbottom` it made the entire document. Besides, even if this is made to work) this way of doing things assumes that the default state (into which the document needs to return after the page is shipped out) is `\flushbottom`, which may or may not be the case (cf. `\ensuremath`).

So the question is, what is the best way to scope the effects of `\raggedbottom` (or some such) to a single page?

(Apologies for no MWE, but it's difficult to come up with one in this case)

### Sample case

If it helps to think about how this could be useful, think of writing a paper in which the references go in an additional page at the end. By default, the last page can be ragged even without `\raggedbottom`. But if the last page will have the references, the "final page" of the document itself would be the page *before* the references.

Maybe in this case (the actual case that motivated me) the changes can be integrated into the bibliography's environment?

Comment: Can't `\clearpage` just be used to create a single ragged-bottomed page?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\clearpage` requires knowing the exact break point.

Comment: @Andrew.  Yes, but if one wants *just one* page ragged, one is doing it with an "intention in mind".  Given the intentionality of the whole thing, one can intentionally place the `\clearpage` with equal effectiveness, in just about all cases of which I can think.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I see the point. But it's easier if you don't need to know the _exact_ place where the page should end, as long as you know that you are in the right page. Still, that's a good point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\afterpage` groups its argument, and as `\flushbuttom` doesn't set its values globally they are lost. You need a "global" variant of `\flushbottom`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\lipsum[1-2]
\pagebreak
\raggedbottom\lipsum[1-2]
\makeatletter
\afterpage{\global\let\@textbottom\relax \global\let\@texttop\relax}
\pagebreak\lipsum[1-2]
\pagebreak abc


\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! And Andrew's answer takes care of reading the current state. However, since that was really more of a cherry-on-top kind of problem, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Excellent - of course it is the scoping issue...

Answer (score 5):

*Updated* `\global` added before `\let` in `\afterpage` as explained in Ulrike Fischer's answer.  Without that the code below does not work as intended - `\raggedbottom` is applied to two consecutive pages not one.  Thanks to StevenB.Segletes for pointing this out.

Here is a version capturing the current setting, assuming the bottom alignment is achieved purely by adjusting `\@textbottom` and `\@texttop`.  This is true in standard LaTeX, and in the `memoir` class.  It does not quite capture `memoir`s `\sloppybottom` though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oneraggedpage}{\let\mytextbottom\@textbottom
  \let\mytexttop\@texttop
  \raggedbottom
  \afterpage{%
  \global\let\@textbottom\mytextbottom
  \global\let\@texttop\mytexttop}}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
%\raggedbottom
\lipsum[1-6]

\vspace{1ex plus 30ex}
\vrule height 10cm
\vspace{1ex plus 30ex}

\oneraggedpage
\lipsum[7]

\vspace{1ex plus 30ex}
\vrule height 10cm
\vspace{1ex plus 30ex}

\lipsum[8-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What am I missing?  When I compile, it appears pages 2 AND 3 are ragged.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your are perfectly right - looking at the result of `\showoutput` page 3 is ragged too and then we get flush after that.  I'll leave this here for the moment as example of code that doesn't work - but isn't as drastically wrong as the poster was expecting.

Comment: I didn't know how `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom` worked. :) However, as informative as it is, there is that problem Steven Segletes pointed out.

Comment: Combining this with Ulrike's `\global\let`s it works as expected. :)