# Ragged bottom only in page in environment

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am taking inspiration from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226716/scoping-raggedbottom-to-a-single-page) to set raggedbottom to only the content of an environment and not the other parts of the document (in a book). However, it seems that the afterpage command and/or usage of global variables does not work as I intend it to in an environment. In the MWE below, you'll see that the text "extbottomexttop" is printed to the second page so it seems that `@textbottom` is not read successfully. I tried using `\@{textbottom}` instead (which I know from other programming languages) but that did not help either.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{chaptertitlepage}{
    \raggedbottom
}{%
    \makeatletter
    \afterpage{\global\let\@textbottom\relax \global\let\@texttop\relax}
    \pagebreak
}

\begin{document}

\begin{chaptertitlepage}
\chapter{First chapter starts here}
It contains information about authors and an abstract which should all fit on the first page.
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{chaptertitlepage}

\section{Introduction}
The other text follows after

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: no need for afterpage just use `\raggedbottom` but force a page break with `\clearpage` at the start and end of the environment

Comment: and you need to make the definition in the scope of `\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother` (putting `\makeatletter` inside the definition does nothing)

Comment: but as it is just 1 page you don't need `\raggedbottom` at all, simply `\clearpage` to force the page break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to force a short (ragged) page break after the environment, so it is enough to call `\clearpage`

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{chaptertitlepage}{\clearpage}{\clearpage}


\begin{document}

\begin{chaptertitlepage}
\chapter{First chapter starts here}
It contains information about authors and an abstract which should all fit on the first page.
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{chaptertitlepage}

\section{Introduction}
The other text follows after

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems the cleanest solution. Could you explain how that works? What does the processor do when it encouters \clearpage which then leads to not being stretched vertically?

Comment: @BramVanroy i`\clearpage` or `\newpage` is a forced page break and leaves the page short just as `\\ ` or `\newline` are a forced line break that leaves the line short. Conversely `\pagebreak` is like `\linebreak` and would force a page but not do anything special with the page so would be justified page or line if that is the current setting.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question uses command names with `@` in the name:

```
\newenvironment{chaptertitlepage}{
    \raggedbottom
}{%
    \makeatletter
    \afterpage{\global\let\@textbottom\relax \global\let\@texttop\relax}
    \pagebreak
}
```

The code `\newenvironment{...}{...}{...}` is parsed immediately, but `\makeatletter` is executed at a later time, when the environment will be executed. But then, the code is already parsed: `\@`, 't', 'e', ...

Use `\makeatletter` earlier during the definition of the environment:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chaptertitlepage}{%
    \raggedbottom
}{%
    \afterpage{\global\let\@textbottom\relax \global\let\@texttop\relax}%
    \pagebreak
}
\makeatother
```